# How to install an app via adb wifi connection?

Tags: android, adb

I have an `MXQ-4k` Box TV and I need to install an app by adb wifi connection since my pc doesn't recognize the USB connection. I can access the device via adb connect `ip:5555`, but when I try to run adb install , the output is:

Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]

There is some way of calling the adb install with the path of some application installer locally at the device, e. g. adb install 192.168.15.5:/storage/emulated/app.apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this:

#### If you have a sdcard, otherwise change the target path:

```
adb connect ip:5555
adb push your.apk \$SECONDARY_STORAGE
adb shell pm install -t -r "\$SECONDARY_STORAGE/your.apk"
adb shell "rm \$SECONDARY_STORAGE/your.apk"
```

You also can try adb install -t "your.apk" and see if it helps.